# How to get mysql db result where `world_id` = '.$world_id.'; on php?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have these mysql tables:

---

(players):

[image]

(environment_killers):

[image]

(killers):

[image]

(player_deaths):

[image]

---

And a PHP page that prints this result:

```
$timenow = time();  
$dayago = $timenow - (86400 * 1);

$monstrums= $SQL->query('SELECT * FROM z_monsters GROUP by name;');

$killers_monsters = mysql_query('
    SELECT COUNT(name) as liczba 
    FROM environment_killers,player_deaths,killers 
    where player_deaths.id = killers.death_id 
        and killers.id = environment_killers.kill_id 
        and name LIKE "%'.$monstrums[name].'" 
        and date > '.$dayago.';');
```

---

**I need this PHP page to print the `$killers_monsters` result where `player_deaths.player_id = players.id` and `players.world_id = '.$world_id.'`**

Comment: Make sure to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: thanks, but i got a simple code above the <?php to prevent it ;)

Comment: Check here $monstrums[name] and mysql_query will give you resource

Comment: Anyway... solved here

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, this is an open Tibia server? XD

Anyway, here you go (assuming your query is correct):

```
if($killers_monsters == true) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($killers_monsters) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($killers_monsters)) {
            echo "Total count: " . $row->liczba . "<br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Total count: 0.<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "An error occured! Total count: 0.<br />";
}
```

Comment: yes, it is! xD. Hey, I didn't really understand what your script does... but I guess you got me wrong ^^. I wanna get the results from $killers_monsters where world_id = '.$world_id.'